# Concentric conducting spheres with dielectric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, dielectric

In the following image, there are 2 concentric conducting spheres. Initially, both are uncharged, outer one is earthed and the space between them is filled with air. After sometime, I somehow put some $q$ in the inner one, then does the outer one gets charge $-q$? Also, does the answer change if the space between them is replaced with another medium of different dielectric constant?
[image: 1]

Comment: Assume that is has charge $x$. The outer sphere is earthed which implies that the potential of the outer sphere is zero. Now, solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The potential of sphere 2 is identically $0$, which means:
$$\frac{1}{4π\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r_2}+\frac{1}{4π\epsilon_0}\frac{x}{r_2}=0$$

The $\frac{x}{r_2}$ is the self-potential while the $\frac{q}{r_2}$ is the potential due to the other body. Now, this means that $x$ is $-q$ which is the answer according to me

Since this involved the calculation of potential directly, I don't think that it should depend upon the capacitance of the medium between the two conductors